# When fetching data from MongoDB using Mongoose, exclude fetching keys based on regex / string matching

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have a fairly large table that needs to be fetched. We have created a compound index that requires the fetch to scan only over the required data, however this still returns ~5K collections each with ~120 keys. We'd like to speed this up further beyond what the compound_index has done for us. We have the following code in our app using `mongoose`:

```
let router = express.Router();
router.get('/big-table/name/:name/school/:school', function (req, res) {
    let name = Number(req.params.name);
    let school = Number(req.params.school);
    db.our_big_table.find({ name: { $eq: name }, school: { $eq: school })
        .then(data => res.json(data))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err))
});
```

We dont need ~60 of the 120 keys, and all 60 of these keys end in the suffix `TTOP`. For example, 3 of these 60 keys may be `ageTTOP`, `heightTTOP`, `sizeTTOP`, ... We could list out every column we want to exclude, as such:

```
let router = express.Router();
router.get('/big-table/name/:name/school/:school', function (req, res) {
    let name = Number(req.params.name);
    let school = Number(req.params.school);
    db.our_big_table.find({ name: { $eq: name }, school: { $eq: school }, '-ageTTOP -heightTTOP -sizeTTOP ...')
        .then(data => res.json(data))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err))
});
```

however it would be great if we could replace the 2nd parameter in our `.find()` function with something along the lines of:

```
db.our_big_table.find({ name: { $eq: name }, school: { $eq: school }, 'doesnt end in TTOP')
```

Is this possible to do with MongoDB / Mongoose?

Comment: I don't think this is supported, you'd need to reorganize your schema.

Comment: okay good to know, thanks